# Send APDU to sim868 via AT+CSIM

Tags: embedded, raspberry-pi3, at-command, sim800

I have GSM/GPRS/GNSS/Bluetooth HAT for Raspberry Pi with SIM868
I want to communicate with sim card over APDU command with AT+CSIM command. The datasheet says that this at command is supported by sim868.
I tried to send the following AT commands:

`AT+CSIM=10,"0070000000"` //Globalplatform manage channel command

`+CME ERROR: unknown`

`AT+CSIM=26,"00A4040008A000000003000000"` //Globalplatform select applet command

`+CME ERROR: unknown`

I have tested these commands via a card reader with the same sim card and it works, but via at command, it doesn’t.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Is the use of `“` (Unicode 'right double quotation mark' (U+201D)) intentional? Is this the exact command you're attempting to send? Try replacing this character with ASCII `"`

Comment: I use right double quotation, it looks like  formatter has changed. I will change not to confuse other. Thanks